# My Google Cloud SQL instance connection and/or queries are too slow

Tags: php, mysql, performance, gcloud

In my job we have the task to see if we can migrate our App database from our current server to a `Google Cloud SQL` instance. I created my GCP, configured the instance and imported the database.

The issue is that I have already connected from my project (a CakePHP localhost App) to the database in `gcloud` and after ran some queries I noticed that they are taking a lot of time and the render of the view is very slow. I have already upgraded the storage of the instance (to have a better read/write speed) and the cores/memory with no results.

Here are some queries and the time they took:

```
Query.                                             Time.    Affected.

GCloud
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_id = 3711;     50ms.    3rows.

Localhost
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE company_id = 3711;     1ms.     3rows.
```

And also the CakePHP DebugKit timer response in one of my views:

```
GCloud    - Controller Action ---- 317.55 ms.
Localhost - Controller Action ---- 7.44   ms.
```

Another view took 3+ seconds using `GCloud` and `164 ms` from my `localhost`.

I used the `us-central1` zone, already upgraded the SSD, cores, RAM, and used small queries like this one to no avail. I think that maybe it has something to do with the latency, but I don't have the slightiest idea.

Im querying from Mexico, to be specific from Jalisco.

My instance is a 2 core with 13gb  of ram `db-n1-highmem-2`

in my localhost `SELECT @@log_bin`returns a 0.

Files:

[php.ini](https://pastebin.com/EJ9qRR9Y)

[my.cnf](https://pastebin.com/SEMv3rpr)

[SHOW GLOBAL STATUS](https://pastebin.com/znehjU4K)

[SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES](https://pastebin.com/X5QwyhDL)

[SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST](https://pastebin.com/2iFthRbk)

```
EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM clients WHERE company_id = 3711;

1   SIMPLE  clients NULL    ref find_by_id,clients_modified,company_id_3,clients_by_creator,clients_by_owner    find_by_id  4   const   3   100.00  Using where

SHOW INDEX FROM clients;

Table   non_unique  key_name            seq_in_index    column_name         collation   cardinality sub_part    packed  null    index_type
clients 0           PRIMARY             1               id                  A           685571      NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 0           PRIMARY             2               user_id             A           685571      NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 0           PRIMARY             3               company_id          A           685571      NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 0           find_by_id          1               company_id          A           1159        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 0           find_by_id          2               id                  A           685571      NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_modified    1               company_id          A           1587        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_modified    2               modified            A           512088      NULL        NULL    YES     BTREE       
clients 1           company_id_3        1               company_id          A           1254        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           company_id_3        2               prospectus          A           3642        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           company_id_3        3               last_update         A           303012      NULL        NULL    YES     BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_creator  1               company_id          A           1503        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_creator  2               user_id             A           3577        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_owner    1               company_id          A           1423        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_owner    2               user_assigned_id    A           3949        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           company_id_3        3               last_update         A           303012      NULL        NULL    YES     BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_creator  1               company_id          A           1503        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_creator  2               user_id             A           3577        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_owner    1               company_id          A           1423        NULL        NULL            BTREE       
clients 1           clients_by_owner    2               user_assigned_id    A           3949        NULL        NULL            BTREE
```

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
Google MODEL or RAM size and number of cores available at  your Google MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
for server workload tuning analysis.

Comment: Geography, please -- Where are you located; where is it located.  49ms could mean that you are on the east or west coast of the US.

Comment: Please provide Google MODEL or RAM size and number of cores available at your Google MySQL Host server.  We can see you have SSD storage.  Thanks

Comment: On your localhost, from MySQL Command prompt, what is result of SELECT @@log_bin; ?

Comment: Please post from Google host TEXT results of EXPLAIN SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE * FROM clients WHERE company_id = 3711; and TEXT results of SHOW INDEX FROM clients;  Thanks

Comment: Done, if you need anything else please let me know. Thank you very much

Comment: Please post from Google host TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE clients;   Disclaimer: I am the content author of website mentioned in my profile, Network profile and would like for you to download from our Utility Scripts page the find-redundant-indexes.sql script and post the TEXT results to allow confirmation of your redundant indexes that appear to exist within your clients table.

Comment: The thing is, you are running the test from your on-prem machine, your Cloud SQL instance is located in us-central, depending on your connexion and the hops that the request have to perform, could be expected to last 300ms. However, the test performed for your current MySQL DB is performed within the same network of your application, hence the latency is really low. So, to me, it's expected, if you want to obtain a lower latency between your app and CSQL, migrate your app to GCP.

Comment: @AdrianEverardoSeguraGarcia Please comment on how the Answer helped your use of MySQL with performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second=RPS - Suggestions to consider for your Google Cloud Database flags - my.cnf [mysdld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 2048 to conserve 95% CPU cycles used for function
innodb_flush_neighbors=0  # from 2 with SSD storage no need to look for neighbors
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G  # from ~ 10G to support less than 1G of data, reduce mgmt cycles
innodb_old_blocks_time=20000  # from 1000 to reduce select_scan RPhr of 1,395
```

Provide feedback, please after implementation + 24 hours of use.